# List Activity Null Pointer Exception. Force Close on Emulator Start Up

Tags: java, android

Here is the code for my ListActivity:

```
    public class CornellRSS extends ListActivity {
    private final static String rssUrl = "http://news.cornellcollege.edu/rss";
    RSSParser parser;
    ArrayList<Message> messages;
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
    parser = new RSSParser(rssUrl);
    loadMessages();
    String[] titles = new String[messages.size()];
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles));
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
        // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
        String keyword = (String) ((TextView) view).getText();
        Message target = getMessage(keyword);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString(RSSHandler.TITLE, target.getTitle());
        b.putString(RSSHandler.DESCRIPTION, target.getTitle());
        b.putString(RSSHandler.LINK, target.getTitle());
        b.putString(RSSHandler.PUB_DATE, target.getTitle());
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), RSSFeed.class);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);
      }
    });

}
```

I keep getting the null pointer exception and can't find a solution. Any help?

EDIT!

The arraylist messages is modified in the method load messages.
The LogCat message at the top is just: "09-28 01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755): java.lang.NullPointerException"

> The full error is: 09-28 01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main 09-28 01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 09-28 01:45:06.726:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
>   09-28 01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323) 09-28
>   01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430) 09-28
>   01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745) 09-28
>   01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670) 09-28
>   01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727) 09-28
>   01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598) 09-28
>   01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260) 09-28
>   01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175) 09-28 01:45:06.726:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338) 09-28
>   01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175) 09-28 01:45:06.726:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
>   09-28 01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
>   09-28 01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047) 09-28
>   01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175) 09-28 01:45:06.726:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338) 09-28
>   01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175) 09-28 01:45:06.726:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140) 09-28
>   01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859) 09-28
>   01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 09-28
>   01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 09-28 01:45:06.726:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 09-28
>   01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 09-28
>   01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 09-28 01:45:06.726:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   09-28 01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 09-28
>   01:45:06.726: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(755):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-28 01:45:08.624:
>   ERROR/InputDispatcher(72): channel '4093eaf0 cc.rss/cc.rss.CornellRSS
>   (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred. 
>   events=0x8 09-28 01:45:08.636: ERROR/InputDispatcher(72): channel
>   '4093eaf0 cc.rss/cc.rss.CornellRSS (server)' ~ Channel is
>   unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Sorry for not making this available sooner.

Comment: if you post the logcat, we'll be able to help you better!

Comment: im guessing the "rssUrl" is a class variable? or any of the other variables like keyword, titles etc...

Comment: also, you titles string array is of size 0 since you initialise it just after initialising ArrayList<messages>, which is empty!

Answer (score 0):

On the `String[] titles = new String[messages.size()];` you need to actually put some values on the titles. The null pointer is probably happening when the ArrayAdapter tries to access your titles and just finds a null pointer.

If that doesn't work them please update your question with the logcat message.